# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type '...' with an OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, winforms, indexer, oledbdatareader

I'm getting the following error on my C# Windows Form application:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ChequeRegistry.oledbDataReader'

The error is on the line with the `if` condition using the `dr` data reader.

**How can I correctly access the first column in the row?**

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr[0].ToString() == txtPassword.Text)
    {
        Main mainform = new Main();
        mainform.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated, but the fact you are comparing a password in plaintext (and therefore transferring it in plaintext over the wire) means you're doing it the wrong way!

Comment: Well, it says you cant do this: dr[0]  So you probably need to just use dr or maybe dr.something

Comment: No.  DataReader only point to the current record in the database,  It is an enumerator.  Use DataAdapter instead.

Comment: Inside the loop datareader cannot mention with index but u can use soemthing like `dr.password.ToString() == txtPassword.Text)` if the column selecting in Select statement is `password`

Comment: Changed the question to clearly express intent.  Cleaned up opening text to improve readability.  Added tag for WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using a custom `OleDbDataReader` that doesn't support the [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz3e7wts(v=vs.110).aspx) (`[]`).

Try using to the [GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead:

```
if (dr.GetString(0) == txtPassword.Text)
```